# unexpected token ) while compiling ejs

Tags: node.js, ejs

I'm very new to Node.js
I'm trying to render twitter tweets to an ejs file using Node js, but getting following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) in C:\achu\samples\nodejs\oneNode\oneNode\views\tweets.ejs while compiling ejs
   at Function (native)
   at Object.Template.compile (C:\achu\samples\nodejs\oneNode\oneNode\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:485:12)
   at Object.compile (C:\achu\samples\nodejs\oneNode\oneNode\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:289:16)
   at handleCache (C:\achu\samples\nodejs\oneNode\oneNode\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:148:16)
   at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\achu\samples\nodejs\oneNode\oneNode\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:358:14)
   at View.render (C:\achu\samples\nodejs\oneNode\oneNode\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:126:8)
   at tryRender (C:\achu\samples\nodejs\oneNode\oneNode\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:639:10)
   at EventEmitter.render (C:\achu\samples\nodejs\oneNode\oneNode\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:591:3)
   at ServerResponse.render (C:\achu\samples\nodejs\oneNode\oneNode\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:961:7)
   at C:\achu\samples\nodejs\oneNode\oneNode\expressDemo.js:17:18
```

**Code is below:**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var twitter = require("twitter");
var client = new twitter({
    consumer_key: "##################",
    consumer_secret: "##################",
    access_token_key: "##################-##################",
    access_token_secret: "##################"
});
//app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get("/:username", function (request, response) {
    var username = request.params.username;
    client.get("search/tweets", { q: username }, function (error, tweets, res) {
        response.locals = { tweets: tweets, name: 'someusername' };
        response.render("tweets.ejs");
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

Can someone please help me in fixing this issue?

Comment: What's with all the extra quotes?

Comment: are you asking about "client" object? If so, that is twitter authentication.

Comment: I think they are typo.. it was populated when I tried to change the values of the keys.. the javascript code which I've written is working fine without any issues.. I'm having issue with EJS file. If I try to write <h2>Hello World</h2> inside the ejs, then I get the error. When the EJS file is empty, then nothing happens. Basically, I wanted to display the tweets in the ejs file.

Comment: I think I got the issue. May be it is issue with the file name, when I try to use the same node js code and render to a different ejs file (eg. quotes.ejs), it worked fine.